# How to take the id of a document with particular name in collection in MongoDB in Node query

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, visual-studio, collections

How to take the id of a document with particular name in collection in MongoDB in Node query.

I have a collection student with fields _id, name, age.. I want to fetch the id of a document which have name field as name :'abcd', I have written `find({name: 'abcd})` and this returns me the whole document.

Comment: Tips for posting here: (1) use formatting and paragraphs to clarify your text; (2) do some initial research, it is quite normal to spend a _continuous_ 30 minutes with a search engine; (3) show the code you are working on, so readers can paste it and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to project the particular field use the query below:

```
db.your_collection.find({"name":"abcd"},{"_id":1}).pretty()
```

**Output**

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("abc")
}
```

You can also add multiple fields in projection like:

```
db.your_collection.find({"name":"abcd"},{"_id":1,"name":1,"age":1}).pretty()
```

**Output**

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("abc"),
  "name":"abc",
  "age":12
}
```

For more about `find` refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#specify-the-fields-to-return).

Comment: can I give this inside match()?

Comment: pipeline: [{ $match: { name: 'abcd' } ,{'_id':1}},], --- to particularly match name abcd and take only id

Comment: Yes, you can, but for that, you have to use the ```aggregation``` instead of ```find``` :)

Comment: Student.aggregate([ { $match: { name: 'abcd'},{_id:'1'} }, --not working